# Пытаюсь создать потокобезопасную очередь с conditional variable

Tags: c++, многопоточность, pthread

Мне надо реализовать потокобезопасную очередь с mutex и conditional variable, используя только <thread.h>. Делаю это без учета, что функции queue stl могут выкинуть ошибку. В самом коде не могу понять, как правильно использовать conditional variable. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть какие то примеры с использованием?

```
template <typename T>
class thread_safety_queue
{
private:
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
public:
    void push(const T& data){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        _queue.push(data);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);    
    }

    bool empty() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        bool temp = _queue.empty();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return temp;
    }

    void get(T& value){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(_queue.empty()){
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }
        value = _queue.front();
        _queue.pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    };

    void peek(T& value){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(_queue.empty()){
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }
        value = _queue.front();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    };

  
};
```

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы для Вашей очереди написали код, который будет ее использовать?

Comment: @KoVadim мне сказали, что я неправльно использую mutex и conditional variable. Я не могу понять, что не так и как правильн использовать переменную

Comment: если придираться к коду, то учитывая что сам код на плюсах, а используется pthread_ функции, то я бы тоже сказал, что это не очень плюсовый код и завернул домашнее задание. Но, закрыв на это глаза, скажу, что функция empty немного не нужна, а функция get может завесить приложение (но это легко лечится специальный сообщением в очередь "все, конец").

Comment: Код нормальный. Я бы добавил флаг, что очередь ждёт сигнал. Чтобы избавиться от лишней работы системы.